# How to check if a list exists in Python

Tags: python

What is the easiest way to check to see if a list or dict exists in python ?

Im using the following but this isn't working:

```
if len(list) == 0:
    print "Im not here"
```

Thanks,

Comment: If there is no object that you've created named `list` in scope, this code will be trying to obtain the length of the built in `list` type. This will result in exception `TypeError`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the lists:

```
if a_list:
    print "I'm not here"
```

The same is for the dicts:

```
if a_dict:
    print "I'm not here"
```

Comment: `list` and `dict` are built in types. This code will always succeed, i.e. the conditions in the `if` statements.

Comment: @mhawke, a_list = list(), bool(a_list) -> False, same for a_dict, and "if statement" is False insensitive. If a_list, a_dict not defined, then we'll have a wonderful and amazing Exception! :)

Comment: @VitalieGhelbert please see the question's revision history - the question has been edited after my comment was made.

Comment: @mhawke, ok, tx u. :)

Comment: WHAT? You mean `if not a_list: print "I am not here"`??

Comment: Perhaps that used to work, but not with 3.7. The try/except solutions below are better

Answer (score 11):

You can use a try/except block:

```
try:
    #work with list
except NameError:
    print "list isn't defined"
```

Comment: I'd go with this unless the OP clarify his question.

Comment: Note that // is integer division. Use # for comments

Answer (score 6):

When you try to reference a non-existing variable the interpreter raises [`NameError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError).  It's not safe, however, to rely on the existence of a variable in your code (you'd better initialize it to None or something).  Sometimes I used this:

```
try:
    mylist
    print "I'm here"
except NameError:
    print "I'm not here"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to name it - it obviously "exists" - I assume you mean to check that it's "non-empty"... The most pythonic method is to use `if varname:`. Note, this won't work on generators/iterables to check if they *will* return data as the result will always be `True`.

If you just want to use a certain index/key, then just try and use it:

```
try:
    print someobj[5]
except (KeyError, IndexError) as e: # For dict, list|tuple
    print 'could not get it'
```

Comment: Or more simply: `if index in list`

Comment: @nicolas If you just wanted to perform a membership test then that's fine, but otherwise I was just pointing out EAFP over LBYL

Answer (score 2):

Examples:

```
mylist=[1,2,3]
'mylist' in locals().keys()
```

Or use this:

```
mylist in locals().values()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple console test:

```
>>> if len(b) == 0: print "Ups!"
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

---

```
>>> try:
...     len(b)
... except Exception as e:
...     print e
... 
name 'b' is not defined
```

Examples show how to check if a list has elements:

```
alist = [1,2,3]
if alist: print "I'm here!"

Output: I'm here!
```

Otherwise:

```
alist = []
if not alist: print "Somebody here?"

Output: Somebody here?
```

---

If you need to check existence/nonexistence of a list/tuple maybe this can be of help:

```
from types import ListType, TupleType
a_list = [1,2,3,4]
a_tuple = (1,2,3,4)

# for an existing/nonexisting list
# "a_list" in globals() check if "a_list" is defined (not undefined :p)

if "a_list" in globals() and type(a_list) is ListType: 
    print "I'm a list, therefore I am an existing list! :)"

# for an existing/nonexisting tuple
if "a_tuple" in globals() and type(a_tuple) is TupleType: 
    print "I'm a tuple, therefore I am an existing tuple! :)"
```

If we need to avoid of ***in globals()*** maybe we can use this:

```
from types import ListType, TupleType
try:
    # for an existing/nonexisting list
    if type(ima_list) is ListType: 
        print "I'm a list, therefore I am an existing list! :)"

    # for an existing/nonexisting tuple
    if type(ima_tuple) is TupleType: 
        print "I'm a tuple, therefore I am an existing tuple! :)"
except Exception, e:
    print "%s" % e

Output:
    name 'ima_list' is not defined
    ---
    name 'ima_tuple' is not defined
```

**Bibliography:** 
8.15. types — Names for built-in types — Python v2.7.3 documentation  https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html

Answer (score 0):

Check (1) variable **exist** and (2) check it is **list**

```
try:
    if type(myList) is list:
        print "myList is list"
    else:
        print "myList is not a list"
except:
    print "myList not exist"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
if 3 in s:
    print("The number 3 is in the list.")
else:
    print("The number 3 is NOT in the list.")
```

You can find more about it here: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/performance/using_key_in_list_to_check_if_key_is_contained_in_a_list.html